# Actualizar Datagridview desde otro formulario en c# llamando método del formulario 1

Tags: c#, windows-forms

escribo en esta oportunidad porque estoy tratando de actualizar un datagridview desde otro formulario, debido que estoy trabajando con 2 formularios, uno se puede visualizar el listado de los productos y en otro formulario tengo un formulario para agregar pero el detalle es cuando le doy en agregar y cerrarse el formulario no me hace nada en el listado, he utilizado este código:

Esto es el formulario 2

```
string rpta = "";
if (this.txtNombre.Text == string.Empty)
{
   this.MensajeError("Falta ingresar algunos datos, serán remarcados");
    errorIcono.SetError(this.txtNombre, "Ingrese un nombre");
}else{
if (this.IsNuevo)
{
    rpta = NModContratacion.Insertar(
                            this.txtNombre.Text.Trim().ToUpper(),
                            1,
                            Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now),
                            Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now)
                        );
 }else{
     rpta = NModContratacion.Editar(
                            Convert.ToInt32(this.txtIdModalidad.Text),
                            this.txtNombre.Text.Trim().ToUpper(),
                            Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now)
                        );
 }

 if (rpta.Equals("OK"))
 {
     if (this.IsNuevo)
     {
         this.MensajeOk("Se inserto de forma correcta el registro");
     }else{
         this.MensajeOk("Se actualizó de forma correcta el registro");
     }
 }else{
        this.MensajeError(rpta);
 }

    this.IsNuevo = false;
    this.IsEditar = false;
    this.Limpiar();
    FrmModContratacion form = FrmModContratacion.GetInstancia();
    form.Mostrar();
    this.Hide();
```

y esto es lo que tengo en formulario 1

```
public static FrmModContratacion GetInstancia()
    {
        if (_instancia == null)
        {
            _instancia = new FrmModContratacion();
        }
        return _instancia;
    }

   public void Mostrar()
    {
        dataListado.DataSource = NModContratacion.Mostrar();
        OcultarColumnas();
        lblTotal.Text = "Total de Registro: " + 
        Convert.ToString(dataListado.Rows.Count);
    }
```

Pero al ejecutar el método Mostrar no me lo actualizo desde el formulario 2, si me pudiera dar una idea que le tendría que anexar.

Comment: Hay algo que no me cuadra en tu código...En tu formulario tienes un método `GetInstancia`, que almacena la instancia del formulario para poder acceder a el desde el otro. Llamas a ese método en el constructor de `FrmModContratacion`? Pq si no, al llamarlo desde el formulario2 lo que va a hacer es crear una nueva referencia al formulario

Comment: No, ahorita lo tengo asi:
          private static FrmModContratacion _instancia;

        public FrmModContratacion()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

Comment: Ese puede ser uno de los problemas. Piensa la lógica. Creas el `FrmModContratacion`. Desde ahí llamas al form2. En el form2 llamas al método estático `GetInstancia`. Como en ese momento _instancia es null, crea un nuevo `FrmModContratacion`, que es la referencia que te devuelve, en lugar de la que a ti te interesa.

Comment: Creo que simplemente debes hacer algo como `_instancia = this;` en el constructor, y devolver siempre _instancia  en `GetInstancia` por ejemplo

Comment: Sii me funciono, muchas gracias :) es recomendable crear una instancia del formulario por cada vez que se abra desde el menú?

Comment: Hmm, a que formulario te refieres? si te refieres al "formulario principal" si, yo recomiendo que una vez que el usuario salga de el,el formulario se cierre y se cree de nuevo cuando sea necesario.

Comment: Listo, ya con la respuesta anterior esta solucionado, muchas gracias

Comment: Me alegro Teresa. Agrego una respuesta por si alguna otra persona tuviera un problema similar al tuyo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sigamos la lógica de tu aplicación.

Creas el `FrmModContratacion`. Desde ahí llamas al `form2`. En el `form2` llamas al método estático `GetInstancia`. Como en ese momento `_instancia` es `null` (nunca la has inicializado), crea un nuevo `FrmModContratacion` y esa es la  referencia que te devuelve, en lugar de la que a ti te interesa.

La solución es sencilla: En el constructor de `FrmModContratacion`, inicializa `_instancia` de la siguiente manera:

```
_instancia = this;
```

De esa manera, `GetInstancia` te devolverá la referencia al formulario correcto.