# ¿Como actualizar un DataGridView de un formulario desde otro formulario?

Tags: c#, windows-forms, visual-studio-2017, datagridview

Estoy intentando actualizar los datos de un DataGridView cuando presiono un botón desde otro. Para explicarme mejor, tengo un formulario principal donde se muestran todos los socios registrados, luego un formulario secundario desde donde creo socios nuevos. Necesito que al momento de presionar el botón que me guarda el nuevo socio me actualice el DataGridView del formulario principal. He intentado lograrlo con una interfaz que comunique a los 2 formularios y llame al método de actualización pero no hace nada. Como aclaración, no estoy buscando pasar datos de un formulario a otro, busco poder llamar al método que se encarga de cargar la grilla pero desde otro formulario secundario.

El codigo del formulario principal:

```
public partial class frm_principal_socio : Form, IForm//implementa la interfaz que cree para llamar al metodo de actualizacion
{
    private void frm_principal_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.llenarCombos();
        this.cargarGrillaInscripciones(svInscripcion.getInscripciones());
        this.WindowState = System.Windows.Forms.FormWindowState.Maximized;
        timer1.Start();
    }

    //metodo para llenar el DataGridView
    public  void cargarGrilla(IList<DTO_Socio> lista)
    {
        dgv_socios.Rows.Clear();
        if (lista != null && lista.Count > 0)
        {
            habilitarBotonesNoError();
            foreach (DTO_Socio dto in lista)
            {
                dgv_socios.Rows.Add(new Object[]
                        {
                            dto.NumeroSocio,
                            dto.Nombre,
                            dto.Apellido,
                            dto.Dni
                        });
            }
        }
    }
    

    //metodo que actualiza la grilla desde la interfaz
    public void actualizarDatos()
    {
        this.cargarGrillaInscripciones(svInscripcion.getInscripciones());
    }
}
```

Codigo de la interfaz

```
public interface IForm
{
    void actualizarDatos();
}
```

Codigo del formulario secundario, este es el formulario que llama al principal:

```
private void btn_guardar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //......aca esta el codigo que valida los textBox y los datos ingresados
    //...

   retorno = (service.registrarSocio(dto) == 1);//valida que en la base de datos se haya creado el socio nuevo y si es correcto retorna 1
   if (retorno == true)
   {
       //bloque de código que debería actualizar el otro formulario
       IForm frm_p = this.Owner as IForm;
       if (frm_p != null)
       {
           frm_p.actualizarDatos();//llamo al actualizar datos del principal
       }
       MessageBox.Show("Socio registrado con exito", "Exito", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
       this.limpiarCampos();
   }
   else
   {
       MessageBox.Show("Hubo un problema al registrar al socio, intente nuevamente", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
       this.limpiarCampos();
   }    
}
```

Agrego el codigo del boton que llama al form para registrar un nuevo usuario:

```
private void btn_socios_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form frm = Application.OpenForms.Cast<Form>().FirstOrDefault(x => x is frm_nuevo_socio);
    if (frm == null || frm.IsDisposed == true)
    {
        frm = new frm_nuevo_socio();
        frm.ShowDialog();
    }           
    else
    {
        frm.BringToFront();
    }               
}
```

Para aclarar, el método que llena el DataGridView funciona perfecto, funciona al momento de iniciar o al momento de aplicarle un filtro en el formulario principal. El formulario de nuevo socio también funciona perfecto ya que registra al socio en la base de dato, el único problema es que no puedo llamar al método para que actualice el DataGridView desde el formulario nuevo socio y así mostrar que se agrego el nuevo socio.

He estado investigando y este código debería funcionar, pero no hace nada, cuando voy al formulario principal están los mismos socios que antes de crear el nuevo. Otra solución es llamar al botón que actualiza el DataGridView, pero tampoco lo hace o posiblemente lo estoy haciendo mal.

Comment: Para lograr lo que deseas tendrás que implementar alguna forma de que tu formulario secundario al cerrarse, devuelva un objeto de tipo `DTO_Socio`, ese objeto devuelto deberás agregarlo a la lista `IList<DTO_Socio> lista`, eso no lo veo en tu código, hay muchas formas de implementarlo, pero siempre tendras que devolver el objeto `DTO_Socio` creado y agregarlo a tu lista.

Comment: Perdón si me explique mal, ahora modifico para que sea mas claro. Pero no trato de pasar datos desde un formulario a otro, lo que busco es llamar al método del formulario principal, el cual se encarga de buscar en la base de datos, desde el otro formulario. Se supone que con esa interfaz debería poder llamar al método, pero no se actualiza.

Comment: coloca el método como Publico para que puedas mandar a llamarlo desde cualquier form.

Comment: Ya intente hacerlo publico, pero no lo ve. Por eso intento usando una interfaz que comunique a los 2 form, pero no hace nada.

Comment: Bueno si tu proyecto está enlazado a una Base de Datos, algo en lo que no soy experto, pero tu pregunta no brinda todos los elementos para descubrir el error. 1º ¿Verificaste que el formulario secundario realmente agrega el nuevo articulo DTO_Socio a la base de datos?. 2º Tu pregunta no muestra el código del procedimiento `cargarGrillaInscripciones`, puede que el error esté en el. 3º Si el `DataGridView` se enlaza a datos, no es necesario hacer el `foreach` que haces en el procedimiento `cargarGrilla`, el `DataGridView tiene sus propios métodos que actualizan la información automáticamente.

Comment: Ya agregue las aclaraciones en el código por si sirve. Respondiendo algunos comentarios, los métodos funcionan bien, puedo registrar socios en la base de datos y desde el formulario principal puedo actualizar el DataGridView. El problema es que necesito que se actualice al momento de que se guarda el nuevo socio y asi reflejar el cambio que se produce en la base de datos. El formulario nuevo socio se abre desde el principal.

Comment: El nuevo código publicado me confunde un poco. Entiendo cual es el problema y el objetivo que quieres lograr, Creo entender que cuando te refieres a _"formulario principal"_  se trata de la clase `frm_principal_socio` y que cuando te refieres a _"formulario secundario"_ (el nombre de la clase sería util) es desde donde creas los socios y desde donde quieres ejecutar el método de la interface. Pero me falta saber si **a.-** Principal abre a secundario, **b.-** Secundario abre a principal o **c.-** Ningún formulario abre al otro

Comment: Ya corregí lo que no entendías, yo puse mal el nombre del formulario cuando formule la pregunta acá. El frm_principal_socio abre el frm_nuevo_socio.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Actualizar Datagridview desde otro formulario en c# llamando método del formulario 1](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/195747/actualizar-datagridview-desde-otro-formulario-en-c-llamando-m%c3%a9todo-del-formular)

Comment: Hay muchísimas preguntas de este tipo... Por qué abrir una nueva pregunta, si hay tantas ya respondidas en el sitio?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Franco, ahora que están aclaradas las dudas, te comento que el código no te funciona porque no estás pasando la referencia del `Owner` cuando abres el formulario `frm_nuevo_socio`.

La solución es modificar la invocación del método `ShowDialog()`

```
if (frm == null || frm.IsDisposed == true)
{
    frm = new frm_nuevo_socio();

    //     aquí    |
    //             V
    frm.ShowDialog(this);
}           
else
{
    frm.BringToFront();
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, esta fue una buena solución. Yo había intentado antes pasar el formulario como parámetro pero no me funcionaba sin el interfaz, pero ahora funciona perfecto.